# Can I make Jersey use my MessageBodyWriter instead of returning 204 when a resource method returns void or null?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I want to be able to write methods like this:

```
@GET
@Template(SIGNUP_FORM)
@Produces("text/html")
public void form() {}
```

My MessageBodyWriter matches methods annotated with @Template, so this should work fine. However, Jersey skips my MessageBodyWriter and returns 204 (no content). To work around this, I have to do something like this:

```
@GET
@Template(SIGNUP_FORM)
@Produces("text/html")
public Object form() { return new Object(); }
```

I can't return null either.

Comment: mind if you show your MessageBodyWriter?

Comment: The purpose of MessageBodyReader/Writer is to support arbitrary serialization forms for model objects. So say you have a User and want to expose it as JSON and XML in your API, you would have two MessageBodyReaders/Writers. If you're returning a static form/template, then you can just return that directly from the resource endpoint: public String form() { return SIGNUP_FORM; }